# How can i create a .pkg mac installer for my binary?

Tags: macos, vercel, xcodebuild, pkgbuild, xar

I have a binary file, `foo`. Built using [vercel/pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg).

I would like to bundle this in an installer for mac; A `.pkg` installer file.

It should install the binary in `/usr/local/bin/foo`.

Attempt:

```
$ cd Desktop // <--- foo binary is here
$ pkgbuild --identifier com.foo.pkg --install-location ./usr/local/bin/ --root ./ foo.pkg
```

This creates a .pkg file: `foo.pkg` on my desktop. And when i run `foo.pkg`, it installs the `foo` binary in `/usr/local/bin` correctly, except that it also leaves `foo.pkg` in `/usr/local/bin` also.

How can make `pkgbuild` avoid leaving `foo.pkg` inside `/usr/local/bin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass `--root`, it takes everything in that folder and bakes it into the package. You're running `pkgbuild` in the root that you're building - it seems very likely that you have a copy of `foo.pkg` on your desktop that was created by an earlier run of `pkgbuild`. When you run it again, the old `foo.pkg` is now built into the new package.

Instead, point `--root` at a directory **only** containing the files you wish to package.

Otherwise, use `--analyze` to generate a component list of your root directory. Customize the resulting .plist as necessary (specifying the files you want to include and associated options), then feed it back into `pkgbuild` with `--component-plist`.

You should read the [man page](https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/pkgbuild/) if you haven't already.